# What would be the full range of someone if they could control the entire electromagnetic spectrum?

Tags: physics, super-powers

I am currently writing a character who discover his electro power was far more than what he used to think for most of his life and with the sudden realisation he discovers that he could fully control the entire spectrum.

Since I'm not that great with physics (or anything that is not related to biology) I was wondering what could he do with those powers. Is he like a normal city buster? Could he affect things not normally seen? What would his true potential be?

Comment: As worded: you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened" [questions to avoid](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Have you ever seen what happens to an inhabited planet when it is struck by a photon with the mass of Mars? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to give a proper answer. Depending on how much energy your superhero can create or control at once, with how much precision, and how loosely you want to interpret "control the electromagnetic spectrum"  you can argue for pretty much any effect.

This is because control the spectrum amounts to controlling photons. Photons mediate the electromagnetic force. So you then get control of charged matter, i.e protons and electrons. It would take all day to list all the things you can do with just photons, protons and electrons. . . .

Answer (score 0):

Maser Man

Before I present my conclusion, lets do the full spectrum.

- Radio: Not lethal or disabling except at super high amounts or for extended periods.
- Microwaves: I'll do this one last.
- Infrared: Heat, good in a pinch but easy to disrupt. Disabling and lethal but can be blocked. Infrared could complement microwaves, worse than microwaves as I will show soon.
- Visible light: Lasers, however, since this is visible anyone can see it.
- Ultraviolet: Will tan people, give sunburns, and cancer. Probably illegal and not disabling, people can fight with sunburns.
- X-ray: Cancer again, doesn't actually give you x-ray vision unless you have sensitive material that can sense the x-rays on the other side.
- Gamma rays: Cancer, but more so. Lethal in very high doses, but less than lethal doses are disabling, but in themselves a life altering attack.

Microwave: Invisible, effective at heating, effective deterrent, and not a cancer threat. Not lethal in high doses, but Gamma Rays are your friend there. If someone manages to brave what is essentially a [Active Denial System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Denial_System) you can heat them up even more with infrared.

Now, you may have noticed something, none of these powers are in the visible spectrum, which means your average passerby can't detect the source. This means your character could run into a battle, get behind cover like a cowering civilian, and roast all the enemy combatants without them being aware that you are an attacker. Common muggers and bank robbers won't even consider you a threat if you pretend to comply. You will have the safest super hero alter ego, by just not having one.

In conclusion, make him Maser Man and have him roast bad guys without a costume.

Comment: thank a lot i knew most of it was about radiation but i was not sure on deep it would be thank a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

## Pretty much anything

It sounds like your character has control over the electromagnetic field; this is not good news for the bad guys if true. In physics, there are only 4* fundamental forces; Gravity, Electromagnetism, and the Strong and Weak nuclear force. Gravity only matters on large scales, the strong force keeps atoms together, and the weak force causes nuclear decay. Everything else on the planet is governed by electromagnetism.

Depending on the control of his powers, your character would be able to:

- Destroy anything with a thought by ripping apart it's atoms.
- Make himself invisible by bending light around him.
- Walk through walls or create forcefields.
- Create illusions by changing the wavelength of light.
- Potentially fly, since they could ionize the air (not sure about practicality).
- All of chemistry.

Among a pretty much endless supply of ideas. Needless to say, this character would be *slightly* overpowered, and I would suggest refraining from having complete control over the spectrum.

<sup>*yes, I know that gravity is not technically a force and the other 3 are actually low energy versions of one force, but this is just an approximation.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**He could augment radio signals from far away.**

So people can listen to the college station even if you live in the boonies!  This would just be a public service he does because he digs the album station (and used to have a show there!) but is too cheap to donate.

For more creative endeavors I like to think your hero might claim one frequency as his own and compose songs directly using radio waves, which people can listen to in their cars.   He might do some prank type stuff too, like mixing a beat and some sampling into the radio broadcast of the presidential debate.

Comment: that would be interesting to actually explore as a side gig type of deal